# Building blocks of society

Tags: translation, word-requests

What is the Chinese phrase that means 'building blocks of society'? 积木 literally means blocks but it sounds weird in context.

Comment: s。iciba, examples will supply needed choice, one example: 基本结构单元

Comment: 社会的基础 (possibly with the particle omitted, but generally not) comes up pretty frequently on Google search results, although I'm not sure how accurate it is.

Comment: 基石 as building block works fine

Comment: 根基 also could work

Comment: 基础/基石/根基 means the _foundation_ of society. Building blocks are 组成部分 (building parts), 组成单元 (building units) or 结构单元 (structural units).

Comment: What about 社会的细胞? As the original version is a metaphor.

Comment: 社会根基 - 根基 means foundation

Answer (score 3):

**Building block**

*Oxford*:

> 1 child's toy
>
> 积木
>
> 2 figurative
>
> (basic element)
>
> 基础成分
>
> the basic building blocks of matter
>
> 物质的构成要素

构成要素 seems to be the winner here.

Results for 社会 + 构成要素 on baidu give us a bunch of different sentences that use this pattern:

- 什么是社会?它的构成要素有那些?
- 第三章 社会及其构成要素
- 论社会的构成要素
- ...理解中国人的心理与行为_中国传统社会的构成要素(上)...

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest 基石 for the best answer...for now. However, it may be different if you provide more context, as 基石 is not something like parts, but more like a whole foundation.